Emacs Org Agenda Freezes
Using Mac M3 Pro, Emacs version: 29.4, org-mode version: 9.7.11, Prelude
When I run Org Agenda, it freezes for about a minute. I turned on the debugger and I got this trace. (had to trim to meet the limits)
The same version of emacs and org mode were working fine on my previous laptop (Mac Intel)
Debugger entered--entering a function:
* substitute-command-keys("Quit")
  (let* ((key-cons (and t (let ((idx (or 10 10))) (let* ((parray ...)) (if parray (let* ... ...) (let* ... ...))))))) (if key-cons (if (eq org-element--cache-sync-keys-value (car key-cons)) (progn (cdr key-cons))) nil))
  (or (let* ((key-cons (and t (let ((idx ...)) (let* (...) (if parray ... ...)))))) (if key-cons (if (eq org-element--cache-sync-keys-value (car key-cons)) (progn (cdr key-cons))) nil)) (let* ((begin (org-element-begin element)) (type (org-element-type element)) (key (cond ((memq type '...) (1+ begin)) ((eq type 'section) (1- begin)) ((eq type 'org-data) (- begin 2)) (t begin)))) (if org-element--cache-sync-requests (progn (let* ((value (cons org-element--cache-sync-keys-value key))) (if (eq (org-element-type element t) 'plain-text) (org-add-props element nil :org-element--cache-sync-key value) (let (...) (if parray ...) element))))) key))
  org-element--cache-key((plain-list (:standard-properties [188660 188660 188660 188691 188691 0 nil planning element t nil nil nil nil #<buffer work.org> nil ((188660 4 "- " nil nil nil 188691)) (section (:standard-properties [188660 188660 188660 188691 188691 0 nil section element t nil 188660 188691 nil #<buffer work.org> nil nil (headline ...)]))] :type unordered)))
  (org-element--cache-key-less-p (org-element--cache-key a) (org-element--cache-key b))
  org-element--cache-compare((plain-list (:standard-properties [188660 188660 188660 188691 188691 0 nil planning element t nil nil nil nil #<buffer work.org> nil ((188660 4 "- " nil nil nil 188691)) (section (:standard-properties [188660 188660 188660 188691 188691 0 nil section element t nil 188660 188691 nil #<buffer work.org> nil nil (headline ...)]))] :type unordered)) (headline (:standard-properties [190193 190193 190208 190600 190600 0 (:title) section element t nil 190210 190600 2 #<buffer work.org> [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-deferred nil t] nil nil] :pre-blank 0 :raw-value [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :title [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :level [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :priority [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :tags [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :todo-keyword [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :todo-type [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :footnote-section-p [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :archivedp [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :commentedp [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t])))
  avl-tree--do-enter(org-element--cache-compare [[[[[[... ... ... -1] [... ... ... -1] (plain-list ...) 0] [[... ... ... 0] [nil nil ... 0] (headline ...) -1] (headline (:standard-properties ... :pre-blank 0 :raw-value ... :title ... :level 4 :priority nil :tags nil :todo-keyword "DONE" :todo-type done :footnote-section-p ... :archivedp ... :commentedp nil)) -1] [[[... ... ... -1] [... ... ... -1] (plain-list ...) 0] [[... ... ... 0] [nil nil ... 0] (headline ...) -1] (headline (:standard-properties ... :pre-blank 0 :raw-value ... :title ... :level 4 :priority nil :tags nil :todo-keyword nil :todo-type nil :footnote-section-p ... :archivedp ... :commentedp nil)) -1] (plain-list (:standard-properties [188318 188318 188318 188382 188382 0 nil planning element t nil nil nil nil #<buffer work.org> nil ... ...] :type ordered)) 0] [[[[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... -1] (headline ...) -1] [[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... -1] (headline ...) -1] (headline (:standard-properties ... :pre-blank 0 :raw-value ... :title ... :level 3 :priority nil :tags nil :todo-keyword nil :todo-type nil :footnote-section-p ... :archivedp ... :commentedp nil)) 0] [[[... ... ... -1] [... ... ... 0] (headline ...) 1] [[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... 0] (table-row ...) 0] (table-row (:standard-properties ... :type rule)) -1] (headline (:standard-properties [189688 189688 189719 189757 189757 0 ... nil element t nil 189721 189757 4 #<buffer work.org> ... nil ...] :pre-blank 0 :raw-value [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-raw-value ... t] :title [org-element-deferred org-element-property-2 ... nil] :level 4 :priority nil :tags nil :todo-keyword "TODO" :todo-type todo :footnote-section-p [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-footnote-section-p nil nil] :archivedp [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-archivedp nil nil] :commentedp nil)) 0] (plain-list (:standard-properties [188660 188660 188660 188691 188691 0 nil planning element t nil nil nil nil #<buffer work.org> nil (...) (section ...)] :type unordered)) 1] [[[[[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... 0] (table-row ...) 0] [[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... 0] (table-row ...) 0] (table-row (:standard-properties ... :type standard)) 0] [[[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... 0] (table-row ...) 0] [[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... 0] (table-row ...) 0] (table-row (:standard-properties ... :type standard)) 0] (table-row (:standard-properties [350976 350976 350979 351057 351058 0 nil table-row element t nil nil nil nil #<buffer work.org> nil nil ...] :type standard)) 0] [[[[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... 0] (table-row ...) 0] [[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... 0] (table-row ...) 0] (table-row (:standard-properties ... :type standard)) 0] [[[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... 0] (table-row ...) 0] [[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... 0] (table-row ...) 0] (table-row (:standard-properties ... :type standard)) 0] (table-row (:standard-properties [353600 353600 353603 353681 353682 0 nil table-row element t nil nil nil nil #<buffer work.org> nil nil ...] :type standard)) 1] (table-row (:standard-properties [352288 352288 352291 352369 352370 0 nil table-row element t nil nil nil nil #<buffer work.org> nil nil (table ...)] :type standard)) 1] (table-row (:standard-properties [349660 349660 349663 349741 349742 0 nil table-row element t nil nil nil nil #<buffer work.org> nil nil (table (:standard-properties ... :type org :tblfm nil :value nil))] :type standard)) -1] 0 (headline (:standard-properties [190193 190193 190208 190600 190600 0 (:title) section element t nil 190210 190600 2 #<buffer work.org> [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-deferred nil t] nil nil] :pre-blank 0 :raw-value [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :title [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :level [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :priority [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :tags [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :todo-keyword [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :todo-type [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :footnote-section-p [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :archivedp [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :commentedp [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t])) nil)
  avl-tree--do-enter(org-element--cache-compare [[[[[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... 0] (plain-list ...) 0] [[... ... ... -1] [... ... ... -1] (headline ...) 0] (plain-list (:standard-properties ... :type unordered)) -1] [[[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... 0] (section ...) 0] [[... ... ... -1] [... ... ... -1] (headline ...) 0] (headline (:standard-properties ... :pre-blank 0 :raw-value ... :title ... :level 4 :priority nil :tags nil :todo-keyword "CLOSED" :todo-type done :footnote-section-p ... :archivedp ... :commentedp nil)) -1] (section (:standard-properties [184237 184237 184237 184264 184264 0 nil section element t nil 184237 184264 nil #<buffer work.org> nil nil ...])) 0] [[[[... ... ... -1] [... ... ... -1] (plain-list ...) 0] [[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... -1] (headline ...) 0] (plain-list (:standard-properties ... :type unordered)) 1] [[[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... 0] (table-row ...) 0] [[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... 0] (table-row ...) 1] (table-row (:standard-properties ... :type standard)) 1] (table-row (:standard-properties [349660 349660 349663 349741 349742 0 nil table-row element t nil nil nil nil #<buffer work.org> nil nil ...] :type standard)) -1] (headline (:standard-properties [187244 187244 187259 187465 187465 0 (:title) section element t nil 187261 187465 2 #<buffer work.org> [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-deferred nil t] nil (headline ...)] :pre-blank 0 :raw-value [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-raw-value (3 14) t] :title [org-element-deferred org-element-property-2 (:raw-value) nil] :level 2 :priority nil :tags nil :todo-keyword nil :todo-type nil :footnote-section-p [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-footnote-section-p nil nil] :archivedp [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-archivedp nil nil] :commentedp nil)) 0] 1 (headline (:standard-properties [190193 190193 190208 190600 190600 0 (:title) section element t nil 190210 190600 2 #<buffer work.org> [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-deferred nil t] nil nil] :pre-blank 0 :raw-value [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :title [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :level [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :priority [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :tags [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :todo-keyword [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :todo-type [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :footnote-section-p [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :archivedp [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :commentedp [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t])) nil)
  avl-tree--do-enter(org-element--cache-compare [[[[[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... 0] (headline ...) -1] [[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... 0] (plain-list ...) -1] (headline (:standard-properties ... :pre-blank 0 :raw-value ... :title ... :level 3 :priority nil :tags nil :todo-keyword nil :todo-type nil :footnote-section-p ... :archivedp ... :commentedp nil)) 0] [[[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... 0] (plain-list ...) -1] [[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... 0] (headline ...) -1] (headline (:standard-properties ... :pre-blank 0 :raw-value ... :title ... :level 4 :priority nil :tags nil :todo-keyword nil :todo-type nil :footnote-section-p ... :archivedp ... :commentedp nil)) 0] (headline (:standard-properties [169689 169689 169704 169772 169772 0 ... nil element t nil 169706 169772 4 #<buffer work.org> ... nil ...] :pre-blank 0 :raw-value [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-raw-value ... t] :title [org-element-deferred org-element-property-2 ... nil] :level 4 :priority nil :tags nil :todo-keyword "TODO" :todo-type todo :footnote-section-p [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-footnote-section-p nil nil] :archivedp [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-archivedp nil nil] :commentedp nil)) 0] [[[[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... 0] (plain-list ...) -1] [[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... 0] (headline ...) -1] (section (:standard-properties ...)) 0] [[[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... 0] (plain-list ...) 1] [[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... 1] (table-row ...) 1] (table-row (:standard-properties ... :type standard)) -1] (headline (:standard-properties [187244 187244 187259 187465 187465 0 ... section element t nil 187261 187465 2 #<buffer work.org> ... nil ...] :pre-blank 0 :raw-value [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-raw-value ... t] :title [org-element-deferred org-element-property-2 ... nil] :level 2 :priority nil :tags nil :todo-keyword nil :todo-type nil :footnote-section-p [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-footnote-section-p nil nil] :archivedp [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-archivedp nil nil] :commentedp nil)) 0] (section (:standard-properties [181301 181301 181301 181337 181337 0 nil section element t nil 181301 181337 nil #<buffer work.org> nil nil (headline ...)])) 0] 1 (headline (:standard-properties [190193 190193 190208 190600 190600 0 (:title) section element t nil 190210 190600 2 #<buffer work.org> [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-deferred nil t] nil nil] :pre-blank 0 :raw-value [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :title [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :level [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :priority [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :tags [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :todo-keyword [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :todo-type [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :footnote-section-p [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :archivedp [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :commentedp [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t])) nil)
  avl-tree--do-enter(org-element--cache-compare [[[[[... ... ... -1] [... ... ... -1] (headline ...) 0] [[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... 0] (section ...) 0] (headline (:standard-properties ... :pre-blank 0 :raw-value ... :title ... :level 2 :priority nil :tags nil :todo-keyword nil :todo-type nil :footnote-section-p ... :archivedp ... :commentedp nil)) 0] [[[... ... ... -1] [... ... ... 1] (plain-list ...) 0] [[... ... ... -1] [... ... ... -1] (plain-list ...) 0] (section (:standard-properties ...)) 0] (headline (:standard-properties [144383 144383 nil nil 144440 1 ... section element t nil nil nil 4 #<buffer work.org> ... nil ...] :pre-blank 0 :raw-value [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-raw-value ... t] :title [org-element-deferred org-element-property-2 ... nil] :level 4 :priority nil :tags nil :todo-keyword "DONE" :todo-type done :footnote-section-p [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-footnote-section-p nil nil] :archivedp [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-archivedp nil nil] :commentedp nil)) 0] [[[[... ... ... -1] [... ... ... -1] (headline ...) 0] [[... ... ... -1] [... ... ... -1] (headline ...) 0] (headline (:standard-properties ... :pre-blank 0 :raw-value ... :title ... :level 4 :priority nil :tags nil :todo-keyword "TODO" :todo-type todo :footnote-section-p ... :archivedp ... :commentedp nil)) 0] [[[... ... ... -1] [... ... ... -1] (section ...) 0] [[... ... ... 1] [... ... ... 1] (table-row ...) -1] (headline (:standard-properties ... :pre-blank 0 :raw-value ... :title ... :level 2 :priority nil :tags nil :todo-keyword nil :todo-type nil :footnote-section-p ... :archivedp ... :commentedp nil)) 0] (section (:standard-properties [181301 181301 181301 181337 181337 0 nil section element t nil 181301 181337 nil #<buffer work.org> nil nil ...])) 0] (plain-list (:standard-properties [161895 161895 161895 162016 162016 0 nil planning element t nil nil nil nil #<buffer work.org> nil (... ... ...) (section ...)] :type ordered)) 0] 1 (headline (:standard-properties [190193 190193 190208 190600 190600 0 (:title) section element t nil 190210 190600 2 #<buffer work.org> [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-deferred nil t] nil nil] :pre-blank 0 :raw-value [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :title [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :level [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :priority [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :tags [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :todo-keyword [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :todo-type [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :footnote-section-p [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :archivedp [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :commentedp [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t])) nil)
  avl-tree--do-enter(org-element--cache-compare [[[[[... ... ... -1] [... ... ... -1] (headline ...) 0] [[... ... ... -1] [... ... ... -1] (plain-list ...) 0] (plain-list (:standard-properties ... :type ordered)) 0] [[[... ... ... -1] [... ... ... -1] (headline ...) 0] [[... ... ... -1] [... ... ... -1] (headline ...) 0] (headline (:standard-properties ... :pre-blank 0 :raw-value ... :title ... :level 1 :priority nil :tags nil :todo-keyword nil :todo-type nil :footnote-section-p ... :archivedp ... :commentedp nil)) 0] (headline (:standard-properties [101340 101340 101358 101853 101853 0 ... section element t nil 101360 101853 3 #<buffer work.org> ... nil ...] :pre-blank 0 :raw-value [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-raw-value ... t] :title [org-element-deferred org-element-property-2 ... nil] :level 3 :priority nil :tags nil :todo-keyword nil :todo-type nil :footnote-section-p [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-footnote-section-p nil nil] :archivedp [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-archivedp nil nil] :commentedp nil)) 0] [[[[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... 0] (headline ...) 0] [[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... 0] (section ...) 0] (headline (:standard-properties ... :pre-blank 0 :raw-value ... :title ... :level 4 :priority nil :tags nil :todo-keyword "DONE" :todo-type done :footnote-section-p ... :archivedp ... :commentedp nil)) 0] [[[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... 0] (headline ...) 0] [[... ... ... 0] [... ... ... -1] (headline ...) 0] (section (:standard-properties ...)) 0] (plain-list (:standard-properties [161895 161895 161895 162016 162016 0 nil planning element t nil nil nil nil #<buffer work.org> nil ... ...] :type ordered)) 0] (section (:standard-properties [121398 121398 121398 121410 121410 0 nil section element t nil 121398 121410 nil #<buffer work.org> nil nil (headline ...)])) 1] 1 (headline (:standard-properties [190193 190193 190208 190600 190600 0 (:title) section element t nil 190210 190600 2 #<buffer work.org> [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-deferred nil t] nil nil] :pre-blank 0 :raw-value [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :title [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :level [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :priority [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :tags [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :todo-keyword [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :todo-type [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :footnote-section-p [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :archivedp [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t] :commentedp [org-element-deferred org-element--headline-parse-title (t) t])) nil)
  -mapc #'(lambda ... ...) org-element--cache-variables --old-state))))))
  org-element-cache-map(#f(compiled-function (el) #<bytecode 0x16742eae3ba9dca1>))
  org-get-buffer-tags()
  org-make-tags-matcher(nil)
  org-tags-view(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-tags-view nil)
  call-interactively(org-tags-view)
  org-agenda(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-agenda nil)
  call-interactively(org-agenda nil nil)
  command-execute(org-agenda)


How did you set up the debugger to produce that backtrace? It is not clear to me what the backtrace is telling us. In general, in such situations, the debugger is useless: what you need to produce instead is an execution profile.

If the slowdown/freeze seems to be in the cache code, try turning the cache off by adding (setq org-element-use-cache nil) in your init file and restarting Emacs. If that works, please report it! Use M-x org-submit-bug-report.

@NickD, I did  pkill -SIGUSR2 Emacs-arm64-11

@NickD, Unfortunately setting org-element-use-cache to nil didn't help. How can I share a large backtrace output here?

Okay, absolving the cache is actually good news! Rather, than sharing a large backtrace, it would be better to provide a profile. It may be that substritute-command-keys is taking all the time and that's why you got the backtrace you got, but it also may be a fluke. If the profile shows substitute-command-keys taking a long time (or perhaps some other function) that's an unambiguous piece of evidence.

You could use the debugger as a poor man's profiler: do M-x toggle-debug-on-quit and make sure that it says enabled, and when it's hanging, try C-g and look at the backtrace; then continue and press C-g again after a second or two; repeat a couple of times - if all the backtraces show the same function at the top, then you can be reasonably sure that that function is the culprit. But the profiler should make that clear with much less effort.

Alternatively, do your pkill method a few times and check whether the same function is at the top of each backtrace. If so, just the function at the top of the backtrace should be enough (and maybe an additional few lines for context as you did above): you don't need to post the whole thing. The important thing is whether the backtrace is reproducible.

@NickD, each time backtrace showed different function. I started pruning the .emacs file and after removing this line '(org-directory "~/org") it seems to be working much better. Will keep an eye out for this

How many files are there in ~/org? You should only have the ones that you want to contribute to the agenda in there. The agenda is produced by a double loop: one going over all the dates (seven days for the weekly agenda) and one going over all the files in org-agenda-list: if you have thousands of files in that list, that might explain the "freezing".

36 files. Most files have approx 25 entries, except for couple. In those couple, there are ~500 dates and approx 1000 TODO keywords. If this is inefficient, pls suggest a better way to see all/past open TODOs
